# Replace multiline text with indentation using sed

Tags: bash, shell

I want to change the following lines of code in shell script. The code is from tomcat's web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I want to change the listing's  to true from false. How can I accomplish this in bash.?
How to use sed to replace multiline string? Do we have to take care of spaces when handling multiline using sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the data is in the file `data.xml`, this should do the job:

```
$ sed '/<servlet>/,/<\/servlet>/ {
>        /<init-param>/,/<\/init-param>/ {
>          /<param-name>listings<\/param-name>/,/<param-value>/ s/false/true/
>        }
>      }' data.xml
```

It is rather careful to ensure that it only changes `false` to `true` in the `<param-value>` associated with a `<param-name>listings</param-name>` within an `<init-param>` tag within a `<servlet>` tag, but if spaces appeared unexpectedly, it would get confused (though that could be fixed if it proved necessary).

Output:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I wouldn't recommend using `sed` for editing XML, but where the task is not too difficult, as here, it can be made to serve.